# Run exe with parameters by default

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-registry, windows-11, shortcuts

I'd like to run my browser (Vivaldi) with the `--silent-debugger-extension-api` parameter by default, which I know is possible via a shortcut or batch file. But I want it to run this way for every instance of the app– not just when ran through a specific shortcut. How might I do this?